# Does Dani sings all of the radio songs or only specific ones?

Tags: far-cry-6

When driving a vehicle with the radio on, there is the chance that Dani will start singing the song that is currently playing.

Does Dani sings all of the [songs that play on the radio](https://www.ginx.tv/en/far-cry/far-cry-6-soundtrack-full-list-of-radio-songs) or only specific ones?

Comment: I tried to find videos of Dani singing (either M or F) but I didn't found videos for some specific songs, and I don't know if that is like that in game or nobody has uploaded videos of Dani singing that song.